# how to override mapred.local.dir in mapred-site.xml?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I do not have write access to the directory specified by mapred.local.dir in mapred-site.xml (and no write access to mapred-site.xml either) Is there a way I can override this property per session basis for my Hive jobs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it in the Hive session by executing the following query:

```
set mapred.local.dir='some dir';
```

This should work. The other option is to change the `mapred-site.xml` which Hive refers to.

Make sure the configuration is not marked as final. In which case it cannot be overridden.

Comment: I did that already actually. Besides setting hive.exec.scratchdir and hive.metastore.warehouse.dir for my session, I also set mapred.local.dir to my directory. But it continues to fail (with below error) since it is attempting to use mapred.local.dir specified in mapred-site.xml .                                        
Failed to create directory /tmp/mapr-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/gomzy - No such file or directory
failed to initialize user directory

Comment: Did you check for Final ? Configuration parameters may be declared final. Once a resource declares a value final, no subsequently-loaded resource can alter that value. For example, one might define a final parameter with:

  <property>
    <name>dfs.hosts.include</name>
    <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/hosts.include</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
Administrators typically define parameters as final in core-site.xml for values that user applications may not alter.

Comment: No :-( .. They are not declared as final. Can I have the perimeter mapred.local.dir modified (by my admin) to point to a dynamic directory i.e for a particular user, it would point to a directory in which that user has Write access ?

Comment: You can use : ${user.name} in the xml files. These will automatically resolve to the user name used to run hive.